# Что необходимо знать для реализации длинной арифметики

Tags: c++

Можете подсказать какие нибудь материалы для того, чтобы разобраться с реализацией длинной арифметики на с++ ?

Comment: В ней собственно не так сложно разобраться, но например [вот](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/big_integer) или статья на [хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/172285/). В интернете куча информации про длинную арифметику.

Comment: школьный учебник по арифметике никто не отменял. Сложение/умножение столбиком собственно решает большинство вопросов.

Comment: Вам нужна глава 4.3 [TAOCP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)